# Download XML compressed with Gzip and decompress it with GzipStream

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am trying to download and save an xml file without any associated file information with it(that is what browser write at the top). The provider advised me to decompress output with cURL's --compressed flag...but I am not using php...Any suggestions?

Update: Provider suggested Zlib for decompress...

When I download the file and save it locally with WebClient, it is not ASCII characters, I can see the contents when I download the document tree in the browser from the url given, but when I download it, it does not display something readable

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("url.xml", "D://myfile.html");
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're getting?

Comment: Ask for the compression format, in order to find the right decompression...

Comment: If you're facing compressed output from the web server, that is something system-specific. You will need to find out from the vendor/provider about the details.

Comment: Zlib is the tool to decompress. Compression is done with GZip/Deflate

Comment: What do you get when you go to that URL in the browser?

Comment: this: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."
and the document tree. Nothing on xml version etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what compression my provider did and I changed the question title...I am also posting the answer I found in case someone else is searching for the same function...I used GzipStream

```
WebClient ClientI = new WebClient();
        ClientI.DownloadFile("url.xml", "filePath.xml");

        //decompress data
        string ReadData = "";
        GZipStream instreamI = new GZipStream(File.OpenRead("filePath.xml"), CompressionMode.Decompress);

        StreamReader readerI = new StreamReader(instreamI);
        ReadData = readerI.ReadToEnd();
        readerI.Close();

        XmlDocument xdocI = new XmlDocument();
        xdocI.LoadXml(ReadData);
        xdocI.Save("newFilePath.xml");
```

enter code here